# product of special positive definite matrices

Tags: positive-definite

I have a matrix $A=R\Lambda R^{-1},$ where $R$ is a positive definite upper triangular matrix and $\Lambda$ is a positive definite diagonal matrix. Is $A$ also positive definite? Thank you.

Comment: Normally a positive definite matrix is Hermitian. How do you define a positive definite triangular matrix?

Comment: $R$ is a square matrix with all the eigenvalues positive.

Comment: If you do not care for the matrix being Hermitian then note that the eigenvalues of $A$ are the same as those of $\Lambda$, thus, positive.

Comment: What is your definition of positive definite matrix? Because in most cases, your matrix has to be symmetric (Hermitian) as A.G. had point out.

Comment: Here I don't need $A$ to be symmetric. If $x^T A x > 0$ for all non-zero vectors $x$, $A$ is positive definite.